# How can I make maven resolver jar be loaded?

Tags: java, maven

In order to check how maven get the dependency tree info, I looked into the maven code. I found that there is a log - *"Dependency collection stats:"* from the output of `mvn dependency:tree -X` is from [maven-resolver](https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver) project, so I downloaded the code and modify the log info to *"Mytest Dependency collection stats:"*(in file DefaultDependencyCollector.java), then build the jar - maven-resolver-impl-1.4.1.jar and use it to replace the one in my local maven repository(which located in .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-impl/1.4.1/maven-resolver-impl-1.4.1.jar). Then I do `mvn dependency:tree -X` again, but the output log still remains to be *"Dependency collection stats:"*. Why is my modification doesn't take effect and how should I make it work?

Below is part of my maven output log that contains *"Dependency collection stats:"*.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ dependencies-reading ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=814600, ConflictMarker.markTime=367100, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=297, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=390100, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=85800, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=63, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=4345400, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=167, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=886684200, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=6158200}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9:compile
```

Comment: Do you have a "real" goal besides understanding the inner mechanisms of the dependency plugin? If you need something "similar" to the tree goal, it might better to write your own plugin or fork the dependency plugin for your own purposes (with your own version number!). Replacing existing jars is kind of "undefined behaviour", so it might or might not work depending on the circumstances.